# Why is my library/Documents shortcut showing all files from all subfolders in one flat list?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I am using Windows Explorer on Windows 7.
In My Documents there's a folder 02 KOOP. If I go there using the adress bar:
D:\users\username\My Documents\02 KOOP
I get a view of my subfolders and some files:

[image]

However when I use the Documents shortcut under Libraries, and then go to the 02 KOOP folder, all files that are located in all subfolders are listed in one big list. When you view the file properties, the actual location is shown:

[image]

This is the only subfolder of My Documents that has this behaviour.

Did I accidentally change some setting, or is something wrong?

Is this some setting I accidentally changed?

Comment: Right click on My Documents (under libraries), select properties. Make sure there is only 1 entry and it is at C:\Users\YourName

Comment: Made sure, but no change

Comment: This seems like it could be a corrupt registry or similar, I'd seriously think about a Windows Repair.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and this fixed it. Right-click on "Documents" and make sure the library is optimized for "General Items" NOT "Documents". If you select "Documents" it doesn't show any subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed it by following these steps:

1. Right-click the library and select Properties.
2. Change the "Optimize this library for" setting from "General Items" to "Documents".
3. Click OK.
4. Change the "Optimize this library for" setting  back to "General Items".
5. Click OK.

Comment: That's identical to the already accepted answer, right?

Comment: @korro The accepted answer is to "make sure the library is optimized for 'General Items'".  My library was already configured for "General Items".  I fixed the recursive-file-list-view by toggling the setting as explained above.

Comment: ah now I see! wow thats even more weird than my situation..